# Oracle Apex5: I get NULL from &MY_ITEM. even MY_ITEM have a value in my current Session

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

First of all, excuse my poor English.

I'm new to the oracle application express (Apex) and I'm kind of confused about maintaining.

I have a simple page with one item `P2_ITEM1` and one button `BUTTON1`.

The button action is defined by dynamic action, and I defined two actions: 
Execute PL/SQL with the following

```
APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('P2_ITEM1',:P2_ITEM1);
```

Alert to show the value of `&P2_ITEM1`.

What I'm expecting to see is an alert with the value of `P2_ITEM1` that I have entered, but I always get null.

Here is a snapshot of the page design and page run.

[image: Page design]

[image: Page run]

Here I'm expecting to have the value `123` but it's always `NULL` UNLESS I submit the page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: cross-post of https://community.oracle.com/thread/4034923

Comment: `&P2_ITEM1.` is a substitution variable which is evaluated when the page is rendered, i.e. before your page sets the value; this is why it is null. To alert the value you need to call `$v('P2_ITEM1')` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeffrey Kemp.
$v('P2_ITEM1') worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `&P2_ITEM1` is a substitution variable which is estimated after the page opened. in your case you just need to use JavaScript as `alert $v('P2_ITEM1')`.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using &P2_ITEM1. , dot in last?